# Function in a controller not getting called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

I'm using this [template](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/) and I'm trying to get some data from the server in a directive's controller.

Here's the directive :

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard')
  .directive('dashboardTodo', dashboardTodo);

/** @ngInject */
function dashboardTodo() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: 'DashboardTodoCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/dashboardTodo'
  };
}
```

and here's the link for the [original controller](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/blob/master/src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboardTodo/DashboardTodoCtrl.js)

and I want to add this function :

```
$scope.getCurrentTasks = function() {
    taskFactory.getCurrentUserTasks()
    .success( function (data) {
        console.log("get Current Users Tasks success : " , data);

    })
    .error(function (data, header, status, config) {
        $scope.errorMessage = "Erreur Current User Tasks : " + data.error + " " + status;
    })
};
```

and I'm calling it right after with : `$scope.getCurrentTasks;`

and Yes I've included `taskFactory` in the dependency list but still the function ain't getting called.

Thank you.

Comment: Provide the place you call the function. Are you sure task factory returns valid promise? Try using .then syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function like

$scope.getCurrentTasks();

You missed the parenthesis to invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the parenthesis to invoke the function:

```
$scope.getCurrentTasks();
```

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but I think that was a typographical error in the question.